# proving differentiability for a function in a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Given a differentiable function $f:D\backslash\{a\}\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)=c$ and $f$ is continous in $a$, I want to prove that $f$ is differentiable in $a$ and $f'(a)=c$.

I've tried the following: 
Let $a_n$ be a sequence in $D\backslash\{a\}$ with limit $a$. By the mean value theorem there is a $\xi_n$ between $a_n$ and $a$ such that $\frac{f(a_n)-f(a)}{a_n-a}=f'(\xi_n)$. Since $|\xi_n-a|<|a_n-a|$ it's $\xi_n\rightarrow a$.

Taking $\lim$ on both sides I get $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(a_n)-f(a)}{a_n-a}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f'(\xi_n)$.

But now I am stuck. Why is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f'(\xi_n)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)=c$ and the other side the differential quotient $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\frac{f(a)-f(x)}{a-x}$? Is $a_n$ arbitrary? Thanks for helping!

Comment: See Theorem 5.31 in http://math.uga.edu/~pete/2400full.pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypothesis that $\lim_{x\to a}f\,'(x)=c$ immediately implies that if $\langle\xi_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is any sequence in $D$ converging to $a$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f\,'(\xi_n)=c$.

> More generally, if $g$ is any function, and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}g(x_n)=c$ for every sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converging to $a$. If you’ve not seen a proof of this, you should try proving it.

The same thing is happening on the other side, only now the function $g$ is not $f\,'$, but rather

$$g(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\;.$$

Comment: thanks. then I'll get $c=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f'(a_n)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(a_n)-f(a)}{a_n-a}$ and so the prove is finished,right? and do we have to choose $a_n$ arbitrary? Because the left and right hand sided differential quotient has to be equal...?

Comment: @user31035: Right. If $g(x)$ is the difference quotient, and you know that $g(x_n)$ converges to $c$ whenever $x_n$ converges to $a$, then you can conclude that $f'(x)=\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=c$. If that last limit were not $c$, you could find a sequence of $ x_n$'s converging to $a$ such that the $g(x_n)$'s did not converge to $c$. This is the converse of the inset result in my answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. One last question: $a_n$ has to be arbitrary in the proof or can we just consider e.g. $a_n<a$ ?

Comment: @user31035: No, you need to consider arbitrary sequences in $D$ that converge to $a$. It’s possible that $D$ is such that these sequences are all on one side of $a$, in which case $f$ has only a one-sided derivative at $a$, but all you actually know is that there **are** sequences in $D$ that converge to $a$, and the converse of inset theorem requires considering all of them.

Comment: Now I am confused. is the proof (I did) still working or not?

Comment: @user31035: You used arbitrary sequences in $D$ converging to $a$, so you’re okay, provided that you have the inset result and its converse.

Comment: thanks a lot. then I will prove 'your theorem' and I am done :)